# Is NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch comparison option missing in MonoTouch?

Tags: .net, ios, nsstring, xamarin.ios, cultureinfo

I want to compare two strings using the iOS `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` comparison option, but I cannot find it in the MonoTouch libray. Is it missing?

Is there any .NET alternative that I can use?

The NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch comparison option is very importand to get good search results on alphabets with diacritics like Greek and Scandinavian, without having the user to type the diacritics.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look for `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` and `NSStringCompareOptions` do not show them as available in MonoTouch.

However you have [culture-aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.aspx) string comparison available in .NET but I do not know of a **general** way to compare string without considering diacritic characters. The best approach would be to [remove such characters](http://www.siao2.com/2007/05/14/2629747.aspx) before doing an ordinal comparison (see blog entry).

If you're porting code, or really needs `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` support, then you can fill a bug report (Enhancement) at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and someone will add the missing bindings in a future release of MonoTouch.

**UPDATE**: MonoTouch 5.2 will [support](https://github.com/mono/maccore/commit/66e34011c035ef86242f4d5460ac1c9e72ce45ab) `NSString.Compare` including its options like `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`.